# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and GRUB2

Tags: grub2

My GRUB2 ver 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.4 will not automatically boot into Ubuntu. It keeps coming up into the GRUB OS Boot Selection screen although I only have the 1 OS listed. I have tried a number of resolutions on my own and cannot get it to boot into Ubuntu directly. I have tried modifying some values in my /boot/default/grub.cfg file  following is what its currently set up as follows:

---

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_SAVEDDEFAULT=true
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="3"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_BACKGROUND="/boot/grub/kali.png"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

export GRUB_MENU_PICTURE="/boot/grub/kali.png"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate matters? Go back to a simple GRUB config.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: I just tried this I commented out all the OLD info and added Just what you suggested. I then ran update-grub and rebooted and still goes back to the Grub Boot menu with no countdown. I must hit enter to get it to go into the OS. Thanks for the suggestion..